# Using powershell I am sending an email from c++ & passing parameters, if 1st param contains "Test Mail" then powershell is taking it as 2 parameters

Tags: c++, powershell, smtp

I am trying to send an email from c++ code using powershell script like below

```
string sSubject = "Test Mail";
string sPsCmd = "Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File ";
string sMailBody = "Please find attachment";
string sFile = "C:\temp\test.txt";
string sMailPsFile = "C:\temp\Mail.ps1"
string sUsermailID = test@test.com
string sCmd = sPsCmd+sMailPsFile+" "+sUsermailID+" "+sFile+" "+sSubject+" "+sMailBody;
system(sCmd.c_str());`
```

Powershell script

```
param(
[string]$MailtTo,
[string]$FileToSend ,
[string]$MailSubject,
[string]$Body
)
$SmtpServer = 'smtp.server'  
$SmtpPort = '25'
$SmtpUser = 'testUser'  
$smtpPassword = 'password'  
$MailFrom = 'test@test.com'  
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $SmtpUser, 
$($smtpPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)

$MailCount=0
Send-MailMessage -To $MailtTo -from $MailFrom -Subject $MailSubject -Body $Body -Attachment 
$FileToSend -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Port $SmtpPort  -UseSsl -Credential $Credentials
$Host.Exit
```

But the script taking parameters as below

```
param1 MailtTo = test@test.com
param2 FileToSend = filePath
param3 MailSubject = Test
param4 Body = Mail
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] of the C++ code you use to invoke the power-shell script.  And **copy-paste** it into the question body, not rewrite it (because when you rewrite you could by accident add other unrelated problems, which you have).

Answer (score 3):

That's normal shell behaviour, you need to quote any parameter containing a space (as well as various other *metacharacters*).

Like this

```
string sSubject = "\"Test Mail\"";
```

Single quotes will also work (I'm not a PowerShell expert however)

```
string sSubject = "'Test Mail'";
```